# Indexing and searching Windows keywords

Tags: search, metadata, indexing

In Windows I added keywords to files (mainly pictures) as metadata using details in properties menu of file where I added my keywords as *Tags*.   The values are stored as *XP Keywords*, *Last Keyword XMP* and *Subject*.

How could I search files using this keywords quickly? (`exiftool ... | grep ...` is too slow.) Probably, it will be necessary to set indexing of this keywords. How can I do it?